# How to exclude some strings in C# Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

This is my current code:

```
        var formula = "Scan: \"sample.test\" OR 'batch.id' AND if (results.tune)))";
        if (formula.IndexOf("field(", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
        {
            formula = Regex.Replace(formula, "[a-zA-Z]\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z_]\\w*", "field(\"$0\")");
        }
```

The output looks like:

```
"Scan: \"field(\"sample.test\")\" OR 'field(\"batch.id\")' AND if (field(\"results.tune\"))))"
```

However, I'd like to skip the first two matches. So, if a term is quoted, do not replace it. The expected output should look like:

```
"Scan: \"sample.test\" OR 'batch.id' AND if (field(\"results.tune\"))))"
```

I managed to get the expected result using two passes:

```
        var formula = "Scan: \"sample.test\" OR 'batch.id' AND if (results.tune)))";
        if (formula.IndexOf("field(", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
        {
            formula = Regex.Replace(formula, "[a-zA-Z]\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z_]\\w*", "field(\"$0\")");
            formula = Regex.Replace(formula, "([\"|'])field\\(\"([a-zA-Z]\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z_]\\w*)\"\\)\\1", "$1$2$1");
        }
```

However, I believe it should be possible to make it in one pass, possibly using regex exclude feature, but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perhaps use negative lookarounds and word boundaries to help:

```
(?<![""'])\b[a-zA-Z]\w+\.[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b(?![""'])
```

Also, you can use `@` to avoid having to double escape a lot of things:

```
formula = Regex.Replace(formula, @"(?<![""'])\b[a-zA-Z]\w+\.[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b(?![""'])", "field(\"$0\")");
```

`(?<![""'])` is a negative lookbehind, which makes sure that the character before the first match isn't a quote.

`(?![""'])` is a negative lookahead, a little similar to the lookbehind, except that it checks for the following character.

Comment: Thanks a million. By the way, to use @ to avoid having the double escapes, you need to "" to escape quote, so: formula = Regex.Replace(formula, @"(?<![""'])\b[a-zA-Z]\w+\.[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b(?![""'])", "field(\"$0\")");

Comment: @miliu Oh, you're right, thank you for pointing that out, I'll correct that immediately. :) Also, you're welcome! I'm not that much familiar with C# yet ^^;

Comment: Thank for explanation of lookbehind and lookahead. One more thing I just learnt is that I would normally put a bar to separate chars inside square brackets (so [""|']), but obviously this is not necessary.

Comment: @miliu Oh no, do not put pipes (or bars) into square brackets, because your regex will match them. `[a|b]` will match all of `a`, `b` or `|`. Most characters you usually need to escape in regex lose their special properly when put within square brackets and become literals, but sometimes, some need to be escaped to remain literal, like the quotes here.

Answer (score 0):

What you want are [non-capturing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#noncapturing_group). Form your regex so that you can write your final expression in terms of (only capturing) groups in the regex. Then call Regex.Replace excluding the non-capturing group(s). See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389662/802203) that uses this technique.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I do not understand how non-capturing groups could help me in this case.